# How to make content inside Bootstrap3 thumbnails bleed all the way to the edge?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

See the image below. I'd like the content to extend all the way to the rounded corners.

Note that this content is not just an image and can include an overlay  (.item-screen)

Markup looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="item-picture">
      <a href="blah">
        <img src="blah" class="img-responsive"/>
      </a>
      <div class="item-screen"></div>
    </div>
  <div class="caption">dark picture</div>
  ...
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you put together a Fiddle so that we can see the CSS that's being applied?  I fully expect that the white space is padding, but it's hard to tell from an excerpt of HTML and a screenshot!

Comment: Olaf's fiddle below pretty much covers it (thanks!)

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the image to round it's corners though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took another look after Olaf pointed out that I could remove the padding

I ended up with applying the following CSS:

```
.item a img {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
}
.item .thumbnail { padding: 0px; }
```

I'd tried adding the border radius before, but until I realized you could make a transparent border it came out looking wonky

Answer (score 1):

When you put together a simple [example](http://jsfiddle.net/FgRLg/), and use some browser tools, you will see a small padding `4px` applied to `div.thumbnail`. To extend the picture to the border, remove that padding

```css
div.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgRLg/1/)

If you want to keep the padding at the bottom, you can do

```css
div.thumbnail {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

and having an [image](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images) with round corners

```html
<img src="..." class="img-rounded"/>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgRLg/3/)

Comment: Yup, that gets rid of the padding on the sides, but I'd like to keep that padding below, and need to deal with the corners